# Set default output format in layout in Lyx

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I am writing a layout for a class file.

The corresponding class file specifies several \RequirePackage calls with the [dvips] option, and hence trying to compile the document using pdflatex or any of the other pdf renderers fails.

Unfortunately, pdf output is the default in Lyx. Is there a way to set the default output format to dvi in the layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Help > Customization:

> OutputFormat [format] The file format (as defined in the LyX preferences) produced by this document class. It is mainly useful when OutputType is literate and one wants to define a new type of literate document. The format is reset to “docbook” or “latex” when the corresponding OutputType parameter is encountered.

So in your layout file you could put

```
OutputFormat dvi
```

Comment: When I do this, the document starts off with the View/Update buttons in a disabled state. Then if I press Tools -> Document Settings and go to Output and set the default format to DVI, it seems to produce documents that I cannot open.

If however, I do not include the OutputFormat dvi line and just set the output type to DVI manually, it works.

Comment: @par I can reproduce. It is either a bug in LyX or a misunderstanding on my part. You could send an email (linking to this question) to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org or if you think it's a bug file a report at http://www.lyx.org/trac